# Getting info from a HashMap within a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to get a certain value from a HashMap within a HashMap:

outermap is of type `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>` which contains the following:

```
{
    "9000": {
        "property": "Art",
        "general": "no",
        "finished": "yes"
    },
    "10503": {
        "property": "Art",
        "general": "no",
        "finished": "no"
    },
    "16792": {
        "property": "Art",
        "general": "no",
        "finished": "yes"
    }
}
```

and I want to be able to determine if the inner HashMap's key "finished" has a value of "yes"

Can you please help me in trying to extract this information? Having trouble getting it out...

This may be due to the fact that I'm a bit confused about the how to iterate through multiple hashmaps, should I be populating another hashmap for the innermap? then iterating through that?

Sorry if this doesn't make sense... I can try to clarify if so. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What code did you write to fetch the desired key? Is there any error?

Answer (score 1):

Try `outerMap.get("9000").get("finished")`

There are several ways of iterating maps, the most common way is by getting its keySet

```
for (String outerMapKey : outerMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(outerMap.get(outerMapKey).get("finished"));        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map <String, HashMap <String, String>> outerMap;

outerMap.get("16792").get("finished");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can convert string to a Map> use jsonutils.
Second,process.

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(str,Map.class);

    for (String key : map.keySet()){
        Map<String,String> innerMap = map.get(key);
        if(StringUtils.equals(innerMap.get("finished"),"true")){
            System.out.println("finished is true ,key is " + key);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // create dummy data set
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> data = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
    item.put("property", "Art");
    item.put("general", "no");
    item.put("finished", "yes");
    data.put("9000", item);

    item = new HashMap<>();
    item.put("property", "Art");
    item.put("general", "no");
    item.put("finished", "no");
    data.put("10503", item);

    item = new HashMap<>();
    item.put("property", "Art");
    item.put("general", "no");
    item.put("finished", "yes");
    data.put("16792", item);
    // end dummy data set

    // iterate to find the desired item 
    for (String key : data.keySet()) {
        Map<String, String> items = data.get(key);
        if (items.containsKey("finished") && "yes".equals(items.get("finished"))) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }
```